# How to convert blobUrl to MP3 in ReactJS with javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import {
  useReactMediaRecorder,
   } from "react-media-recorder";

  const { status, startRecording, stopRecording, clearBlobUrl, mediaBlobUrl } =
useReactMediaRecorder({
  audio: true,
  blobPropertyBag: {
    type: "audio/m4a",
  },
});
const audioUpload = async (e: any) => {
     saveMedia(reader.result?.toString(), user);
};
    
    
    const uploadImage = async (
      file: any,
      user: IUser
    ): Promise<IUploadImage | null> => {
      const storage = getStorage(firebaseApp);
    
      const child = "1abcd/koray-test/" + idGenerator();
    
      const imageRef = ref(storage, child);
    
      const snapshot = await uploadToFirebase(imageRef, file);
    
      if (!snapshot) {
        return null;
      }
    
      const fbReference = snapshot.ref.fullPath;
    
      return { fbReference, file };
    };
```